# How to call new activity when click on Drop down navigation in actionbar in android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am following this [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-drop-down-navigation-to-action-bar-in-android/) to implement actionbar.

i have modified this code like this

```
/** Defining Navigation listener */
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + actions[itemPosition]  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(actions[itemPosition] == "Bookmark")
startActivity(new Intent(this,Bookmark.class))
else if(actions[itemPosition] == "Subscribe")
startActivity(new Intent(this,Subscribe.class))
else
startActivity(new Intent(this,Share.class))
                return false;
            }
        };
```

When i run this code it opens Bookmark activity . but it call over main layout like when it opens bookmark and i click back then it opens main activity. i want when i click on list for e.g bookmark then only the activity should change not the title with list navigation. or is there any example that i should follow to call new activity when list navigation is called. i have also tried ActionBarSherlock it also change the textview on clicking list navigation not calling new activity

Answer (score 1):

Try This instead of above

```
    if(actions[itemPosition].compareTo("Bookmark")==0){
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Bookmark.class));
    }       
    else if(actions[itemPosition].compareTo("Subscribe")==0){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Subscribe.class));
    }
    else{
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Share.class));
                    return false;
         }
```

Comment: the issue is not that i just want to open an activity.. i want to open activity on current activity with same title bar..

Comment: You are confused about the nature of `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open new activity on current activity. That's not how it works. If you want to change the views within your activity when the item is clicked you can, and should look into fragments to do so.

Comment: I havnt work with fragments. how can i work with fragments with action bar list? any link ?

Comment: Sorry friend, I haven't worked with fragments either, I just know that it is the preferred method for the effect that you desire. What it basically does is takes the current activity and repopulates the activity with new data. Much info in the Android docs